# jquery not() not removing child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code :

```
var carol = "<h1>something</h1><div><span class='icon-edit'></span> lalalallalala </div>"
$('<div>').append($(carol).not('span.icon-edit')).html()
```

and it still outputs :

```
"<h1>something</h1><div><span class="icon-edit"></span> lalalallalala </div>"
```

basically not is not removing anything.

Why? And how to remove it?

Comment: `.append($(carol).remove('span.icon-edit'))`.

Comment: You're not selecting the element, however returning the same selector i.e. `carol`.

Comment: `.not()` does not work the way you think. It is a filter for the current set of elements, it is not a function to remove child elements.

Comment: @Tushar still not working with remove() as well :(

Comment: @123onetwothree you need to `.find()` and `.remove()` `span.icon-edit` before you append `carol`. jQuery does not handle child-elements inside elements unless you explicitely tell it to.

Answer (score 2):

Taking `carol`:

```
var carol = "<h1>something</h1><div><span class='icon-edit'></span> lalalallalala </div>";
```

When you do `$(carol)` what is created is a jQuery object containing two elements, namely:

- 0: `<h1>something</h1>`
- 1: `<div><span class='icon-edit'></span> lalalallalala </div>`

So, when you call `$(carol).not('span.icon-edit')` you are asking jQuery to filter every `span.icon-edit` off that collection. Then it goes:

- Is `<h1>something</h1>` a `span.icon-edit`? No. Then it keeps it.
- Is `<div><span class='icon-edit'></span> lalalallalala </div>` a `span.icon-edit`? Notice it is "matching" the `div`, not the inner `span`. So, is that `div` a  `span.icon-edit`? Well, no. Then it keeps it.

So, since `.not('span.icon-edit')` filters nothing out of that collection, executing

```
$('<div>').append($(carol).not('span.icon-edit')).html()
```

Is the same as

```
$('<div>').append($(carol)).html()
```

Thus yielding

```
"<h1>something</h1><div><span class="icon-edit"></span> lalalallalala </div>"
```

## Removing the `span.icon-edit` child

Calling `$(carol).remove('span.icon-edit')` on the parent has no effect, due to the same reason above. It finds no `span.icon-edit` in the (top level of the) collection, so it removes nothing.

To get the child out, **you can do**:

```
var carol = "<h1>something</h1><div><span class='icon-edit'></span> lalalallalala </div>"
$('<div>').append($(carol).find('span.icon-edit').remove().end()).html()
```

**Output**:

```
"<h1>something</h1><div> lalalallalala </div>"
```

So, its a combination of:

- [`.find('span.icon-edit')`](https://api.jquery.com/find/): matches the `span` inside the HTML (`carol`)
- [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/): removes the matched `span`
- [`.end()`](https://api.jquery.com/end/): since the `.remove()` will return the removed `span`, and you wanted the original collection, `.end()` to returns the collection to the previous state (where it had the elements `h1` and `div`)

Comment: So, was your problem solved? You can let us know by [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/219205).